# Code doesn't work. But does when debugging

Tags: c, codeblocks

I need some help here and I couldn't find anything relevant by searching.

So I am writing a C program and something weird is going on. My program crashes when I run it normally but when I debug it, it works fine. I don't get what's going on.

It's an assignment and it's due on Wednesday so I am freaking out a little.

(I am using the CodeBlocks IDE, if that's any help.)

EDIT:
Sorry about not posting this from the beginning, I thought the problem might have been me using the debugger wrong or having to change debugger settings (if that's even possible).
Here is the function that seams to be causing the problems:

```
double **makeMatrix(struct graph *head, char **nodes)
{
    double **tmpMatrix=NULL;
    int i=0, j=0;
    struct graph *tmp=NULL;


    if(nodes==NULL || head==NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(i=0; nodes[i] != NULL; i++);

    tmpMatrix=calloc(i+1, sizeof(double*));

    if(NULL==tmpMatrix)
    {
        printf("No Memory!");
        return NULL;
    }

    for(j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        tmpMatrix[j]=calloc(i+1, sizeof(double*));

        if(NULL==tmpMatrix[j])
        {
            printf("No Memory!");
            return NULL;
        }
        tmpMatrix[j][i] = -INF;
    }

    for(i=0; tmpMatrix[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; tmpMatrix[i][j] != -INF; j++)
        {
            tmpMatrix[i][j] = INF;
        }
    }

    for(tmp=head; tmp->fromNode >=0; tmp= tmp->next)
    {
        tmpMatrix[tmp->fromNode][tmp->toNode] = tmp->length;
        printf("%f\n", tmpMatrix[tmp->fromNode][tmp->toNode] );
    }

    return tmpMatrix;
}
```

The assignment is about writing a program that is able to read nodes and graphs to calculate the shortes path. Where were given the Dijkstra algorithm to solve this problem. That's why we have to create an matrix we stores the length of the edges.

Also, with the debugger I was executing it step by step.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: That doesn't have much information for anybody to help you. See [ask].

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow.  In order we can help you, please, consider to post some of your code, the point of crashes, the messages output, log files,...

Comment: If the debug mode zeroes out all variables, that could mask an uninitialized variable (pointer) issue. Some debuggers instead set all variables to a value like 0xcccccccc that will cause a seg fault if used as a pointer.

Comment: You're probably dealing with some sort of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but it could also be any number of other bad things. It's impossible to know from the information you've given.

Comment: `tmpMatrix[j]=calloc(i+1, sizeof(double*));`  --> `tmpMatrix[j]=calloc(i+1, sizeof(double));`

Comment: Yay! You have an [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) :-)

Comment: If @wildplasser's solution does not work, you will have to post lots more. The routine itself, as is, compiles (when I make up `struct graph` and `INF`) but I have no idea with what parameters to run it, and how to verify if it works or not. So voting to close for "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." (Don't be alarmed – close votes can be retracted, if there is good reason to.)

Comment: UB for sure...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems or potential issues depending on all the code and input you haven't shown:

1. The line:

   ```
   tmpMatrix[j]=calloc(i+1, sizeof(double*));
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   tmpMatrix[j]=calloc(i+1, sizeof(double));
   ```

   If `sizeof(double*) == 8` you might be ok by chance but better to be actually correct
2. In the first `for` loop you seem to be counting the size of the `nodes` array. I don't understand the use of nodes in this case since it isn't used elsewhere in the function. A better function signature would be to pass the size of the array needed. Make sure that `nodes` is properly `NULL` terminated or you'll run into issues. I would also add another variable to make the array size explicit since you reuse `i` later on, something like:

   ```
   int arraySize = 0;
   ...
   for (i = 0; nodes[i] != NULL; ++i);
   arraySize = i;
   tmpMatrix = calloc(arraySize + 1, sizeof(double*));
   ```
3. For setting values of `tmpMatrix` to `INF` it would be better to use explicit array indexes, like:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < arraySize; ++j)
       {
           tmpMatrix[i][j] = INF;
       }
   }
   ```

   This makes it much clearer what you are doing and less error prone.
4. You should explicitly check for a `NULL` pointer in your last loop:

   ```
   for (tmp = head; tmp->fromNode >= 0; tmp = tmp->next)
   ```

   If the linked list is not setup correctly then `tmp` may become `NULL` and you'll dereference it causing undefined behaviour. Simply add a check to the loop like:

   ```
   for (tmp = head; tmp != NULL && tmp->fromNode >= 0; tmp = tmp->next)
   ```
5. You should check for valid array indexes for `tmpMatrix` inside your last loop:

   ```
   tmpMatrix[tmp->fromNode][tmp->toNode] = tmp->length;
   ```

   if `tmp->fromNode` or `tmp->toNode` are invalid array indexes you'll overflow/underflow the array and cause UB. Even if you "know" these values should be correct it is far safer to add a check just in case:

   ```
   if (tmp->fromNode >= 0 && tmp->fromNode < arraySize &&
       tmp->toNode   >= 0 && tmp->toNode   < arraySize) 
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

A lot of these points are in the "defensive programming" category. Yes, `nodes` and `head` should be NULL terminated and have correct indices, but maybe there's another bug somewhere and they're not, or invalid input was received, or a stray cosmic ray flipped a bit in a memory cell. By checking your inputs a bit more carefully you can prevent UB from occurring and randomly crashing on you like you've experienced.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. I checked the code a dozen times and every time I overlooked the asterisk that is not supposed to be there. That was the whole damn reason the program crashed. Still weird that it worked while debugging...
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately one outcome of undefined behaviour is nothing...it appears to work fine. Then you change one little, seemingly unrelated thing and it crashes on you.